# Problema con Access

Tags: servidor, ms-access

Solicito la ayuda del grupo sobre el siguiente mensaje de Access.

Comento que solamente ocurre al intentar pasar la base de datos a otro equipo. En mi Laptop funciona perfectamente. Es una Base de datos sencilla para manejo de inventario con posibilidades de llevar otros módulos adicionales.

Trabajo en mi laptop con Windows 10 t Office 2019 y he tratado de pasar esta Base de datos a distintas versiones de Access pero nada. (2007, 2010, 2013 y la ultima prueba fue en 2016).

El error dice textualmente lo siguiente:

La expresión 'Al hacer clic' que ha especificado como valor de la propiedad de evento produjo el error Ocurrió un problema mientras SAI-CargoH&G se comunicaba con el servidor OLE

*La expresión no da como resultado el nombre de una macro, de una función definida por el usuario o [Procedimiento de evento]
*Hubo un error al evaluar la función, evento o macro.

Este error se produce cuando un evento no se ha podido ejecutar debido a que no se puede evaluar la ubicación de la lógica del evento. Por ejemplo, si la propiedad OnOpen de un formulario se establece en =[Campo], este error se produce porque se espera que se ejecute un nombre de evento o macro al producirse el evento.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y como podriamos ayudarte sin ver tu codigo, o saber cuando pasa eso... que pongas el error esta genial, pero nos falta contexto... ni siquiera sabemos que tratas de hacer...}

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es el error.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim documento As DAO.Recordset

'obtenemos el usuario
Set documento = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from usuarios where username='" & [Form_Inicio].Texto37 & "'", dbOpenDynaset)
documento.MoveFirst

'vemos si tiene nivel de permiso 0 y de ser asi bloqueamos los campos para que no se pueda editar
If documento!nivel_de_permiso = 0 Then
    Me.Project.Enabled = False
    Me.Project.Locked = True
    
    Me.Item.Enabled = False
    Me.Item.Locked = True
    
    Me.PO_number.Enabled = False
    Me.PO_number.Locked = True
    
    Me.Supplier_Subcontractor.Enabled = False
    Me.Supplier_Subcontractor.Locked = True
    '---
    Me.PO_Description.Enabled = False
    Me.PO_Description.Locked = True
    
    Me.Bond_type.Enabled = False
    Me.Bond_type.Locked = True
    
    Me.Location.Enabled = False
    Me.Location.Locked = True
    
    Me.Amount.Enabled = False
    Me.Amount.Locked = True
    
    '--
    Me.Currency.Enabled = False
    Me.Currency.Locked = True
    
    Me.Bank.Enabled = False
    Me.Bank.Locked = True
    
    Me.Expiry_Date.Enabled = False
    Me.Expiry_Date.Locked = True
    
    Me.Comments.Enabled = False
    Me.Comments.Locked = True
    
    
    
End If

documento.Close
Set documento = Nothing
```

End Sub

Ese es el codigo, por lo que he leido no tiene que ver con el codigo, ya que en otro equipo funciona correctamnete. He visto que access no se comporta muy bien a la hora de pasar la base de datos a otro equipo, pero bueno a lo mejor hay alguna solucion.

Comment: Lo primero seria depurar el código que indicas para saber en que linea se provoca el error. Sabes hacerlo? Supongo que no lo has hecho. Tienes que crear un punto de interrupción al principio del código [con F9 o haciendo click en el margen izquierdo}, abrir el formulario en cuestión e ir avanzando con F8 linea a linea. Al recibir el error, recuerda la ultima linea activa ya que esa sera la que provoca el error.